# Can't add sub-entities in Linq2Sql

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 entity types Buyers and BuyerOrders. Buyer can contain multiple BuyerOrders and list of BuyerOrders can be edited by users. When I want to add some BuyerOrders I call method:

```cs
private static void CreateOrdersForBuyer(Buyer buyer, int[] selectedLeadTypes)
{
    foreach (var order in selectedLeadTypes.Select(leadTypeId => new BuyerOrder
         {
             Buyer = buyer,
             OfferTypeID = (int) OfferTypes.Referral,
             Price = 1,
             RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now,
             StatusID = (int) BuyerOrderStatus.Pending,
             LeadtypeID = leadTypeId,
             Profit = 1
         }))

    {
        buyer.BuyerOrders.Add(order);
    }
}
```

And then save the buyer:

```
GenericRepository.Instance.Save(buyer);
```

Save method:

```
public virtual void Save<T>(T value) where T : class
{
    //LegalLeadsDataContext.Instance = null;
    LegalLeadsDataContext.Instance.GetTable<T>().Attach(value);
    LegalLeadsDataContext.Instance.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, value);
    LegalLeadsDataContext.Instance.SubmitChanges();
}
```

After that I see no new BuyerOrders in Database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.refreshmode.aspx)

**KeepCurrentValues**: Forces the Refresh method to swap the original value with the values retrieved from the database. No current value is modified.

Whereas the `KeepChanges`

**KeepChanges**: Forces the Refresh method to keep the current value that has been changed, but updates the other values with the database values.

Also, the Attach method, use the overload that allows you to specify "as modified".

So in your code, it would appear that possibly you need to change

```
public virtual void Save<T>(T value) where T : class
{
    //LegalLeadsDataContext.Instance = null;
    LegalLeadsDataContext.Instance.GetTable<T>().Attach(value, true);
    LegalLeadsDataContext.Instance.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges, value);
    LegalLeadsDataContext.Instance.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: strange, but no effect. I tried the solution from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636618/linq-2-sql-insert-objects-with-associated-child-objects-list-into-database-s but when I'm saving new BuyerOrder entity it creates a new buyer, nevertheless I set all foreign keys correctly

Comment: @valerii.sverdlik: see my updated answer. try the Attach method that allows you to make the entity "modified" when it is attached.

Comment: @valerii.sverdlik: Have you been able to try the GetTable<T>().Attach(value, true) method yet?